# Create Visualforce page with dynamic number of GaugeSeries charts

Tags: apex, visualforce, gaugeseries

I want to display, on a single page, a gauge chart for each record of a certain type (Scholarship Campaign) that is currently active. This number may change at any time, and the specific records being pulled may change at any time. With apex:gaugeSeries, you load a list of data and it uses the first entry only for that chart. My idea was to then create a list that contains all of those data lists `List<List<GaugeData>> lofl`, then iterate through that list on the Visualforce page. This does not seem to work however; it does not render anything on the page with it set up that way.

My Code with the Nested List Set Up:

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="BaselineBMark_Controller" action="{!init}">
<apex:form >
    <br/>   
    {!message}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!lofl}" var="l">

        <apex:chart height="250" width="450" animate="true" legend="false" data="{!l}">
            <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="gauge" margin="-10" minimum="0" maximum="35" title="" />
            <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="links" highlight="true" tips="false" donut="50" needle="false" colorSet="green, red">
            </apex:gaugeSeries>
        </apex:chart>

    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public Class BaselineBMark_Controller
{
    public String message {get; set;}
    public Boolean status {get; set;}
    public List<Scholarship_Campaign__c> activeCamps {get; set;}
    public List<List<GaugeData>> lofl {get; set;}

    public PageReference init()
    {
        lofl = new List<List<GaugeData>>();
        return null;
    }

    public List<GaugeData> getData()
    {
        activeCamps = [SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Number_of_Links_Gained__c FROM Scholarship_Campaign__c WHERE Is_Current__c = 1];
        message = 'Campaigns loaded successfully.';
        List<GaugeData> data = new List<GaugeData>();
        for (Scholarship_Campaign__c camp : activeCamps)
        {
            if (data.size() > 0) data.clear();
            data.add(new GaugeData(camp.Name, (Decimal)camp.Number_of_Links_Gained__c));
            lofl.add(data);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public Class GaugeData
    {
        public String name {get; set;}
        public Decimal links {get; set;}
        public Decimal lowRange {get; set;}
        public Decimal highRange {get; set;}

        public GaugeData(String name, Decimal linksTo)
        {
                this.name = name;
                this.links = linksTo;
                this.lowRange = 7;
                this.highRange = 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that at present you are adding the same list multiple times. Replace `if (data.size() > 0) data.clear();` with  `List<GaugeData> data = new List<GaugeData>();` (i.e. the declaration inside the loop) and you will at least have independent lists with their own content. Also check your browser's JavaScript console for error messages.

Comment: ... and you should e.g. call `getData` in the `init` so `lofl` is not just an empty list but is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cut-down version of your controller will display 10 gauge charts with your page. It has the changes made in my comments applied with the data hard coded; replace the for loop with your query and use your `GaugeChart` class.

```
public with sharing class BaselineBMark_Controller {

    public String message { get; set; }
    public List<List<GaugeData>> lofl {get; set;}

    public PageReference init()
    {
        lofl = new List<List<GaugeData>>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            List<GaugeData> data = new List<GaugeData>();
            data.add(new GaugeData());
            lofl.add(data);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Class GaugeData
    {
        public String name {get; set;}
        public Decimal links {get; set;}
        public GaugeData()
        {
            this.name = 'random-' + Math.random();
            this.links = Math.random() * 35;
        }
    }
}
```

Replace:

```
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

with your query:

```
    for (Scholarship_Campaign__c camp : [
            SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Number_of_Links_Gained__c
            FROM Scholarship_Campaign__c
            WHERE Is_Current__c = 1
            ]) {
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Cutting out the getData() method and adding the data right from init() helped tremendously.