# Gauge Chart not visible in vf page

Tags: visualforce, gaugeseries

I am trying to get the gauge chart in my vf page but when i am trying with below code nothing is visible on vf page. could anyone please help me.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="gaugeController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:chart height="250" width="450" animate="true" data="{!data}">
                    <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="gauge" title="Transaction Load"
                               minimum="0" maximum="100" steps="10"/>
                    <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="data1" donut="50" 
                                      colorSet="#78c953,#ddd"/>
                </apex:chart>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Does your controller provide a list of objects that each have a `data1` field name in its `data` field? See [A Simple Charting Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm).

Comment: Thanks for reply Keith, but if i just wants to pass one value to the gauge then how would i do that since the gauge can show one value at a time.

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124316/create-visualforce-page-with-dynamic-number-of-gaugeseries-charts for an example; the GaugeData class can just have one property.

Comment: @Keith thanks a lot that worked for me but if there is no value in my list then the graph is not visible, but if i wants to show the graph even for zero how to show that.

Comment: Perhaps a single list entry with `data1` set to zero?